# How to add corresponding classes to the body element when each radio button is clicked in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

I want to add a specific class to the body tag and active class to the parent element when I click on each radio buttons.

Eg:

```
<form action="">
 <input type="radio" value="layout1">Layout 1<br>
 <input type="radio" value="Layout2">Layout 2<br>
 <input type="radio" value="Layout3">Layout 3
</form>
```

When I click the radio button with the value 'layout1', a class 'a' should be added to the body tag and it should change to class 'b' and 'c' accordingly when I click on each radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import DOCUMENT from angular

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  layout1;
  layout;
  layout3;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) { }   
  addClass($event) {
    if (this.document.body.classList) {
      let className = Object['values'](this.document.body.classList).filter(d => d !== $event);
      className.map(d => this.document.body.classList.remove(d));
      this.document.body.classList.add($event);
    }
    else {
      this.document.body.classList.add($event);
    }

  }

}
```

**component.html**

```
<form #f="ngForm">
 <input type="radio" value="a" (ngModelChange)="addClass($event)"[ngModel]="layout1" name="1"  ngModel>Layout 1<br>
 <input type="radio" value="b"(ngModelChange)="addClass($event)" [ngModel]="Layout2" name="1"  ngModel>Layout 2<br>
 <input type="radio" value="c" (ngModelChange)="addClass($event)" [ngModel]="layout3" name="1" ngModel>Layout 3
</form>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ffxib

Comment: Is there any way to add multiple classes to the body?. I want to add multiple classes to the body tag if I click on some radio buttons.

Comment: yes you can use     this.document.body.classList.add($event); it will append the class like a b c

Comment: I tried to use this snippet to change the colors of my navbar inside the same component, but not working !!. A class '.navbar-primary', '.navbar-success' etc should be added to the navbar in the same way.

Comment: are you trying to change the colour?

Comment: Yes. I tried the same code by changing the selector body to navbar.

Comment: inspect the navbar element and check whether the class is appending to the nav bar or not

Comment: The class is not added.

The code i have used:

`NavbarVariation($event) {
    if (this.document.querySelector('.navbar.default-layout').classList) {
      let className = Object['values'](this.document.querySelector('.navbar.default-layout').classList).filter(d => d !== $event);
      className.map(d => this.document.querySelector('.navbar.default-layout').classList.remove(d));
      this.document.querySelector('.navbar.default-layout').classList.add($event);
    }
    else {
      this.document.querySelector('.navbar.default-layout').classList.add($event);
    }
  }`

Comment: instead of doin this you can use ngClass

Comment: hi what is your requirement when you change the radio button you want to add class to the nav?

Comment: Yes, I want to add a class `.navbar-primary` to the navbar when `.tiles.primary` is clicked, and `.navbar-danger` when `.tiles.danger` clicked, and the other classes when `.tile.*` clicked accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182002/discussion-between-chellappan-and-febul).